# Grails Convert SQL into Grails criteria query

Tags: sql, grails, criteria-api, detachedcriteria

I have following domain structure :-

```
class A{
  B b
  C c
  String email
}

class B{}

class C {
  D d
}

class D{}
```

Below is my SQL query which I needed to convert into Grails Criteria Query.

```
select * from A aa  
  inner join C ca on ca.c_id = aa.id and aa.email = 'source'
  inner join D da on da.id = ca.d_id
  inner join B ba on aa.b_id = ba.id
  inner join A aa1 on b.id = aa1.b_id and aa1.email = 'response'
```

Comment: `inner join B ba on a.b_id = b.id`... what `a` and `b` stand for?

Comment: @injecteer Sorry, it was typing mistake. it is aa.b_id = ba.id

Comment: here also `A aa1 on b.id = aa1.b_id and aa1.email = 'response'` ?

Answer (score 0):

in order to implement the query you want with hibernate/GORM you must extend your domain classes a bit:

```
class A{
  B b
  C c
  String email
  A a // self-ref
}
```

then your query should look like:

```
A.withCriteria{
  eq 'email', 'source'
  a{ 
    eq 'email', 'response'
  }
}
```

Comment: ,Is this not possible to without adding A a // self-ref.

Comment: no, criteria doesn't allow `join`s over other than domain class fields. If you still need to do some wild joins, you have to stick with the SQL/HQL query

Comment: @ injecteer, we can use detachedcriteria as subquery to make join. But I got stuck at point ..

Answer (score 0):

I have renamed the tables to something that makes sense like:

```
class Apple{
  Ball ball
  Cat cat
  String email
}

class Ball{}

class Cat {
  Dog dog
}

class Dog{}
```

And the create criteria is:

```
return Apple.createCriteria.list() {

    and {
        and {
            eq("email", "source")
            cat
        }
        and {
            cat {
                dog
            }
        }
        and {
            eq("email", "response")
            ball
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a real data and let me know if you need any help.

You can also look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/biniama/ac2fca32f6a5be2c21c6).

Comment: @ Biniam if I add the following it make result list size 0.                            and {
            eq("email", "response")
            Ball {}
    }

Comment: @SumitVerma      I have changed the code. Please test it now. (I removed the {} after Ball and Dog and renamed Ball to ball and Dog to dog - referring to the object not the class)